# What kind of wheels need different nipple for front vs. rear?

Tags: wheels, spokes, nipples

I'm shopping for spoke nipples and I see some described as specifically for front or for rear.  Is this just a marketing tactic, or do some wheels need different ones like this?

Comment: I'm inclined to say its marketting, but I can imagine different wheels front and rear that need different sizes or shapes.   Get Brass nipples unless you're a weight-weenie - aluminium nipples are lighter but round off easier and don't hold as well or for as long.

Comment: There are cases where the front and rear wheels are radically different, in terms of their spokes, but such cases would usually be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Those are Motorcycle spoke nipples. Bicycles can have different spokes and nipples between the front and rear wheels but there is no standard.